# wso2 ESB iterate mediator to handle nullity

Tags: wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I call a wso2 DSS data service, which will return available database rows as response. 
I use an [Iterate mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Iterate+Mediator) to iterate over the elements and perform the required task.

My issue is when the database has no entries, the data service doesn't return a response but the iterate mediator starts to iterate and throws up an exception in the ESB. Is there a property to tell the iterate mediator **only to iterate if elements are available**? 
Similar to a java `if (null)` check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if there is data before calling iterate mediator  :

```
<filter xpath="boolean($body/something)">
    <then>
        --> iterate
    </then>
</filter>
```

xpath expression return true if "something" node exist

Comment: $body/a_sub_element didn't work. can you please let me know what should come in the "something" please?

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)